# Oracle, average team stats by individual players throws exception

Tags: oracle

I want to calculate the average productivity of all teams in a icehockey  competition. To do this, I want to make a query to calculate the productivity of each player and take the average of it for having the productivity of 1 club. To calculate the productivity of 1 player, I divide the number of goals by the played games. number of goals from 1 player.

I tried it to use following query:

```
SELECT TEAM.CODE, (1 - AVG(SUM(TS.GOALS)) / SUM(CS.GAMES) * 100) AS "Percentage"
FROM DIM_TEAM TEAM 
JOIN PLAYER P ON P.TEAM_ID = TEAM.ID
JOIN TEAM_STATS TS ON TS.PLAYER_ID = P.ID
JOIN COMPETITION_STATS CS ON P.ID = CS.PLAYER_ID
GROUP BY TEAM.CODE;
```

I'm totally stuck, because I get following exception:

> Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
>
> SQLState:  42000 ErrorCode: 937

The code worked in the past, but I think the business implementation is also wrong. Can anyone help me to figure this out?

Comment: Prepare http://sqlfiddle.com with structures and sample data so we can move on

Comment: In order to solve this, more data is needed on the structure of your data.

Comment: You are nesting aggregates in your example.  ```avg(sum(ts.goal))```  Compute your sums first and then apply avg().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the sum(ts.goals) as that is the reason for your error and I don't think it is needed.  You need to beware of divide by zero in this query though..

```
    SELECT TEAM.CODE, (1 - AVG(TS.GOALS) / SUM(CS.GAMES) * 100) AS "Percentage"
    FROM DIM_TEAM TEAM 
    JOIN PLAYER P ON P.TEAM_ID = TEAM.ID
    JOIN TEAM_STATS TS ON TS.PLAYER_ID = P.ID
    JOIN COMPETITION_STATS CS ON P.ID = CS.PLAYER_ID
    GROUP BY TEAM.CODE;
```